# Calculating possible combinations with N number of characters for the length of M

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Calculating possible combinations with N number of characters for the length of M starting with any single character.

e.g. I have set of N characters {a,b,c}, I want to find possible combinations for length M.

If M = 2, First character should be 'a'.

Possible combinations are 3: {a,a}, {a,c}, {a,b}

If M = 3, First character should be 'a'.

Possible combinations are 9: {a,a,a}, {a,a,c}, {a,a,b}, {a,c,c}, {a,b,b}, {a,c,b}, {a,b,c}, {a,b,a}, {a,c,a}

How to achieve this? Please help.

Comment: In the second case, why aren't a,b,a and a,c,a possible combinations?

Comment: Yeah those are possible combinations. Updated question

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you have one choice for the first character and three choices for each of the remaining $M - 1$ characters.  Also, you are describing ordered sequences rather than combinations.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig right.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one choice for the first position and three choices for each of the remaining $M - 1$ positions, then the number of sequences you can form is $1 \cdot 3^{M - 1} = 3^{M - 1}$.  You can verify that this formula works for the examples you have considered.